# I can see a Laravel 6 intallation in localhost

Tags: laravel, apache, ubuntu

I was testing a clean Laravel 6 installation to migrate an old Laravel project in one Ubuntu 18.04 environment, no used with PHP projects before.

After install PHP, Apache, Mysql... I test one PHP page OK.

I set the permissioins to 777 in `/var/www/html/` subdirectories.

I cloned my old Laravel App to migrate and did one clean Laravel 6 installation.

First, I loaded the default welcome page in Laravel 6. After, I put some routes and views from the old project and tried to load some of then, but I had errors of type:

> page don't found

I checked the settings of *Apache* and if *mod_rewrite* was available... finally, I run the old project OK, but **my *Laravel 6* is dissapeared**. I can see it in the disk, but if load the `http://localhost/laravel/` directory I can't see it.

> Edited

Content of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did you try http://localhost/laravel/public/[route]?

Comment: @symlink, yeah. Before I could load 'http://localhost/laravel/myapp/public/' before, not 'http://localhost/laravel/ironwoods/public/zzz' for example (404). Now, I get a 404 in all cases, for the server 'http://localhost/laravel/myapp' don't exist

Comment: please check the sites-enable/000-default file in your etc/apache2 folder and see where the apache root is set

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I chedked this file content... I think this is no the problem. Added its content to the question.

Comment: and inside the /var/www/html what's your folder stucture?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I have a laravel folder with my laravel projects inside. I see all and run they, except the disappeared one, no visible and not accessible from the web navigator...

Answer (score 0):

What i can suggest you to try is to define one Virtual Host for each project in this way:

Put this (with proper information) inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/YOUR_LARAVEL_PROJECT_ROOT/public"
    ServerName yourProjectDomain.dev
    <Directory "/var/www/html/YOUR_LARAVEL_PROJECT_ROOT/public">
            AllowOverride All
            Options FollowSymLinks +Indexes
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And inside `/etc/hosts` put

```
127.0.0.1     yourProjectDomain.dev
```

Then check the permission on `/var/www/html` and each subdirectory (you can use `cd /var/www/html && sudo chmod -R 777 *` to set everything as readable, writable and executable).
Then clear the cache of the project (delete all the files inside the `bootstrap/cache` folder).
Then you should be able to access that project just using `yourProjectDomain.dev` on every browser inside your pc.